# Filter for changing MediaElement.js Settings

Tags: media

I am trying to change some of the settings that get loaded with MediaElement.js. I can't seem to find a filter or hook to alter the settings that are loaded. The only way I was able to customize the settings is by opening up the core MediaElement.js file and changing the settings there.

Obviously this is less than ideal, because I'm forced to edit a core WordPress file which will be overridden on update. How can I change the settings using a filter so my settings aren't lost?

I am trying to set

```
enableKeyboard: false
```

Comment: Which of the settings precisely are you interested in changing?

Comment: enableKeyboard: false

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I need to do something similar to use iOS/Android native controls on the audio/video player.

Comment: I never was able to find a solution to this. I tried multiple solutions including separate js/jQuery functions, none of it worked as I needed it too. Surprised no one ever wrote a response here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copy `wp-includes/js/mediaelement/wp-mediaelement.js` into your theme or plugin and make your modifications there. For example, I added some settings to force the use of native video controls on iOS & Android devices, like so:

```
(function ($) {
        // add mime-type aliases to MediaElement plugin support
        mejs.plugins.silverlight[0].types.push('video/x-ms-wmv');
        mejs.plugins.silverlight[0].types.push('audio/x-ms-wma');

        $(function () {
                var settings = {
                        // Put your custom MediaElement.js Player Options here...

                        alwaysShowControls: true,
                        // force iPad's native controls
                        iPadUseNativeControls: true,
                        // force iPhone's native controls
                        iPhoneUseNativeControls: true,
                        // force Android's native controls
                        AndroidUseNativeControls: true
                };

                if ( typeof _wpmejsSettings !== 'undefined' )
                        settings.pluginPath = _wpmejsSettings.pluginPath;

                $('.wp-audio-shortcode, .wp-video-shortcode').mediaelementplayer( settings );
        });

}(jQuery));
```

You can then use an action to dequeue the original and enqueue your modified version. If you're doing this in a theme, add the following to your functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_mediaelement_settings' );
function my_mediaelement_settings() {
        wp_deregister_script( 'wp-mediaelement' );
        wp_register_script( 'wp-mediaelement', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/js/wp-mediaelement.js", array( 'mediaelement' ), false, true );
}
```

This assumes you put your modified `wp-mediaelement.js` file inside a `js` directory within your theme.

Answer (score 3):

Since WordPress 4.4 there actually *is* the filter [mejs_settings](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/mejs_settings/), which does exactly what you want.

In your case:

```php
add_filter('mejs_settings', function ($settings) {
    $settings['enableKeyboard'] = true;
    return $settings;
});
```

---

If anyone is interested, it works like this: `wp-includes/script-loader.php` turns this into an inline `<script>` in the `<head>` that sets a global JS object `_wpmejsSettings`, which, on `domReady`, is passed to the `.mediaelementplayer()` function in `wp-includes/js/mediaelement/wp-mediaelement.js`.